# How can I disable web security in selenium through Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Apparently it's common for google-chrome to get this: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-740

The key is to start it without security enabled. To disable security,

```
"--disable-web-security",
```

I'm having trouble wondering how to actually specify these command line arguments, though, so it fails on the `open` invocation here:

```
from selenium import selenium

sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*googlechrome', 'http://www.google.com/')
sel.start()
sel.open('/')
```

Here's how I start the selenium server:

```
shogun@box:~$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I had to create an external script to wrap the chrome browser.  Place a script somewhere your Selenium server can reach it (mine is at `~/bin/startchrome`, and chmod it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chrome expects to be run from the .app dir, so cd into it
# (the spaces in the path are a Mac thing)
cd /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
exec ./Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-security $*
```

Then in your Python code, do this:

```
from selenium import selenium

browser = '*googlechrome /Users/pat/bin/startchrome'
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, browser, 'http://www.google.com')
sel.start()
sel.open('/')
```

Comment: If that doesn't work try changing --disable-security to --disable-web-security